# Embedding constant at specific memory location

Tags: c, embedded

I'm writing a bootloader for an embedded application on the NXP S12ZVL32.  I need the application to be aware of the version (major, minor, build) of the bootloader.  Is it possible to declare constants at a specific location in the bootloader source so the application can find them?

I tried declaring constants at the start of a #pragma section so I would know where it started.

```
#pragma CODE_SEG SHADOW_ROM
const UINT8 VER_MAJOR = 0xFE;
const UINT8 VER_MINOR = 0xED;
const UINT16 VER_BUILD = 0xCEFA;
```

S12 is little endian, so I expected to be able to search the generated .sx file for FEEDFACE, but could not find even FEED or FACE.  I have optimization turned off, so the compiler shouldn't be removing unused constants.

Comment: You've created an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  *"I need the application to be aware of the version (major, minor, build) of the bootloader"* -- That's a low-quality design that imposes an unnecessary burden on the app.  Instead the interface between bootloader and app should be clearly defined with a corresponding version number.  How that version number is passed to the app is part of the API.

Comment: @sawdust Why do you believe this is an XY problem? This is a reasonably common solution for identifying the version of something on an embedded system.

Comment: @sawdust The reason that the application would need to know the bootloader version is so that when a bug is inevitably discovered in the first version of the bootloader, the software can know that it needs to apply the workaround, if the new bootloader without the bug isn't installed.

Comment: The available means to do this are tool-chain specific - what is your tool-chain?  `#pragma` directives unrecognised by your tool chain will be ignored - possibly but not necessarily with a warning.  The compiler/linker need not place separate variables in any specific order, adjacency or alignment - use an array `UINT8 VER[] = {0xFE, 0xED, 0xFA, 0xCE} ;` to force the order and alignment you desire.

Comment: @sawdust, There is no API in a situation like this.  The bootloader and the main application are completely separate and independent entities, and must remain so.  They cannot by definition talk to each other.  The bootloader simply jumps to the application entry point when it times out on a reset or when it is finished reflashing app code.  Are you sure you're not thinking Windows programming?

Comment: @(other)Jeremy: In this context, the API is the shared knowledge about the location of version information - as indeed is the shared knowledge about how the bootloader locates and invokes the entry point of the main app.  That it's not a function call interface doesn't stop it being an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to locate a constant at a specific memory address.  There are different ways to accomplish this and the details of how to do this vary from one tool-chain to another.  One way is to use a compiler-specific `#pragma` or `_attribute_` statement in the source code definition to specify the memory address where the constant should be located.  Another way is to customize the linker directive (aka linker script or scatter load) file by creating a special memory section at the desired memory address.  Then use a `#pragma` in the code or another linker instruction to place the constant into the custom memory section.  See your tool-chain documentation for details.

Comment: This was helpful.  I found the NXP documentation on S12Z constant, variable and code allocation in codewarrior.  This told me everything I need to know.

https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-334387

Answer (score 0):

First of all, defining a global `const` value allows the compiler to use the value only (as an rvalue, as you normally don't reference the address of `MATH_PI`) and to use the value at each place it could be needed.  If you want a constant to be placed in a fixed site, the best way to specify is in assembler.

When I was young, I used to use the `whatis` unix command to see the `#(@)` prefixed string in which was normally stored the version info in SCCS revision system.  When I had to switch to cvs, I used the idea to define constants in each source file, and search (this can easily be made with  `grep(1)` or some filter program) to scan the binary (yes, the binary code of the program) for lines that started in `$Id:`  so I embedded lines like:

```
static const char CVS_id[] = "\n$Id$\n";
```

in source files, and when `grep(1)`ping the binary, I got the whole revision for each module linked in the executable.

Git doesn't put by itself a version string, but the best (because it doesn't need to put things in absolute addresses) is to put the version info in a string with some specific pattern (git allows to put it for yourself by means of a *git hook*) not to be confused with other thing by the scanning code.  This way you can get the version info of each source file included, with just scanning the binaries.

All of this doesn't require you to fix things to fixed places, so from my point of view allows more flexibility to your memory map and gives you a more portable way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bootloader and main app are both under your control, you could have the bootloader jump to the application entry point with a pointer to the version information (and any other information you wish) in a register, for the app to make use of as it sees fit.  This eliminates any reliance on fixed memory locations.